# Not able to get mobile data enabled or disabled in nougat and marshmallow

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-7.0-nougat

I have added below permission and defined broadcast receiver

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name=".CheckLockBroadCastReciever" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            <!--<action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />-->
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>`
```

My defined receiver is calling when I am doing mobile data on/off in jellybeans os, KitKat os and lollipop os but the receiver is not invoking in marshmallow and nougat.

Comment: what error u getting any logcat ?

Comment: I am not getting any error, receiver "CheckLockBroadCastReciever" is not revoking automatically when I manually enabling or disabling mobile data in marshmallow and nougat

Comment: add the java code here

Comment: public class CheckLockBroadCastReciever extends BroadcastReceiver  {      Context mCOntext;      @Override     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
Toast.makeText(context, "Called, internet response called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}

Comment: sorry, unable to paste in right code format. toast message is not getting called.

Comment: Did u registered ur received inside onCreate , using intent filter?

Comment: Now, I registered and working. Thanks for your help :). Please edit your answer, I will accept that

Comment: Man I edited my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133807/discussion-between-ajay-kurmi-and-w4r10ck).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `permission`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Also, try to register your reciever inside `onCreate` and don't forget to unregister and register inside `onPause` and `onResume` respectly.

Answer (score 0):

The network changes listener implementation for android N and high

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        registerReceiver(mNetworkReceiver, 
                new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
 }
```

Please refer https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html